# Is there a way to keep the rich text formatting when exporting data from a Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

I have a google sheets document and want to export the data, some of the text has *italics* and I want to keep that formatting in the export either as markdown or *html* tags. Is that possible?

When exporting as csv there is no option, and using the googleapis npm module you can pass in  valueRenderOption as 'FORMATTED_VALUE' but that doesn't seem to do anything with text.

Does anyone know a way?

Comment: From `I want to keep that formatting in the export either as markdown or html tags. Is that possible?`, in this case, how about exporting the Spreadsheet as HTML? By this, the text style in the cell is exported as HTML.

Comment: Ooh that does seem to have formatting as `<span style="font-style:italic;">` around the parts I want, I can use that with some parser to get what I need, thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.